# sqlite compound where datetime queries

Tags: sqlite, datetime, where-clause

I have a 'presure' table in an sqlite3 database with a 'timestamp' column filled by datetime('now') by a python program which runs periodically adding line at a time to my table.

I'd like to query the database so as to return all the values just from today.

Easy enough:

```
select * from presure where timestamp like "2014-07-10 %";
```

BUT, I don't want to have to modify the query each time I run it, today ,tomorrow or any other day. So what I want is someway to replace the date string and wild card with a sub query that generates todays date like:

```
select date('now');
```

but I have been unsuccessful compounding the two queries. What am I missing?

Comment: Try `LIKE strftime('now`, 'YYYY-MM-DD) + ' $'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, strings are concatenated with `||`:

```
SELECT * FROM presure WHERE timestamp LIKE date('now') || '%'
```

Comment: Modified this a bit to: SELECT * FROM presure WHERE timestamp LIKE date('now', 'localtime') || '%' and it works. Thanks!